# Firebase Cloud Functions Deployment Fail - service agent's IAM roles

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I am facing an issue while deploying my Firebase Cloud Functions. The project has three functions: `http`, `onSchedule` and `onObjectFinalized`. The `http` and `onSchedule` functions deploy successfully, but I encounter an error when deploying the `onObjectFinalized` function.

The complete error message I receive is:

```
$ npm run deploy:prod

> cloud-functions@1.0.0 deploy:prod      
> npm run changeToProd && firebase deploy


> cloud-functions@1.0.0 changeToProd
> firebase use prod

Now using alias prod (zipshot-prod)

=== Deploying to 'zipshot-prod'...

i  deploying functions, hosting   
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8581

{"severity":"WARNING","message":"params.PROJECT_ID.value() invoked during function deployment, instead of during runtime."}

{"severity":"WARNING","message":"This is usually a mistake. In configs, use Params directly without calling .value()."}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"example: { memory: memoryParam } not { memory: memoryParam.value() }"}

i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged F:\project\chrome_ext\zipshot\cloud-functions\functions (109.47 KB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: ensuring required API run.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API run.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: generating the service identity for pubsub.googleapis.com...
i  functions: generating the service identity for eventarc.googleapis.com...
i  functions: Failed to verify the project has the correct IAM bindings for a successful deployment.
i  functions: You can either re-run `firebase deploy` as a project owner or manually run the 
following set of `gcloud` commands:
i  functions: `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding zipshot-prod --member=serviceAccount:service-1090842465135@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/pubsub.publisher`
i  functions: `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding zipshot-prod --member=serviceAccount:service-1090842465135@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`
i  functions: `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding zipshot-prod --member=serviceAccount:1090842465135-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/run.invoker`
i  functions: `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding zipshot-prod --member=serviceAccount:1090842465135-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/eventarc.eventReceiver`       

Error: We failed to modify the IAM policy for the project. The functions deployment requires 
specific roles to be granted to service agents, otherwise the deployment will fail.
```

Here's a snippet of my `index.js` file:

```js
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {onObjectFinalized} = require("firebase-functions/v2/storage");
const {getStorage} = require("firebase-admin/storage");
const {onSchedule} = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler");
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");
// const Storage = require("@google-cloud/storage")
// const {tmpdir} = require("os")
const path = require("path")
const sharp = require("sharp")
// const fs = require("fs-extra")

// const gsc = Storage()

initializeApp();

const app = require("./app.js");
const {projectID} = require("firebase-functions/params")

exports.apiv2 =  onRequest({minInstances: 2}, app)

// currently running after every 10 mins
exports.callUploadAfterEveryXmin = onSchedule("*/10 * * * *", async() => {
   ...
})

/**
 * When an image is uploaded in the Storage bucket,
 * generate a preview image automatically using sharp.
 * This code creates a 600x300 preview image for the 
 * image saved in a temporary directory, then uploads 
 * it back to Cloud Storage.
 */
exports.generatePreviewImg = onObjectFinalized(async (event) => {

    const fileBucket = event.data.bucket; // Storage bucket containing the file.
    const filePath = event.data.name; // File path in the bucket.
    const contentType = event.data.contentType; // File content type.
  
    // Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
    if (!contentType.startsWith("image/")) {
      return logger.log("This is not an image.");
    }
    // Exit if the image is already a preview image.
    const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
    if (fileName.startsWith("preview_")) {
      return logger.log("Already a Preview Image.");
    }
  
    // Download file into memory from bucket.
    const bucket = getStorage().bucket(fileBucket);
    const downloadResponse = await bucket.file(filePath).download();
    const imageBuffer = downloadResponse[0];
    logger.log("Image downloaded!");
  
    // Generate a preview image using sharp.
    const previewBuffer = await sharp(imageBuffer).resize({
      width: 600,
      height: 300,
      withoutEnlargement: true,
    }).toBuffer();
    logger.log("preview image created");
  
    // Prefix 'preview_' to file name.
    const thumbFileName = `preview_${fileName}`;
    const thumbFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbFileName);
  
    // Upload the preview image.
    const metadata = {contentType: contentType};
    await bucket.file(thumbFilePath).save(previewBuffer, {
      metadata: metadata,
    });
    return logger.log("Preview image uploaded!");
  });
```

I have the roles of `Cloud Functions Admin` and `Editor` The deployment script is as follows:

**package.json:**

```json
"scripts": {
    "deploy:prod": "npm run changeToProd && firebase deploy",
    "changeToProd": "firebase use prod"
}
```

**.firebaserc:**

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "dummy-dev",
    "dev": "dummy-dev",
    "prod": "dummy-prod"
  }
}
```

I have tried checking the documentation and forums, but I couldn't find a solution. Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is with the Function `Service Agent` (service account) and not your identity. Edit your post with the service agent's IAM roles plus include the deploy command and the build messages.

Comment: Hello, @JohnHanley, thank you for your input. I've made edits to the post. Could you please guide me on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The error message shows you the commands to use. Did you run those commands?

Comment: Yes I have tried, getting this error:


ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) User [user@gmail.com] does not have permission to access projects instance [dummy-prod:setIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): Policy update access denied.

Comment: You will need to contact someone who has the required permissions in your company.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and I succeed to work arround it by manually creating the function from GCP.

One probable origin of this error may be that I had an "App Engine" service account from 1st generation of Cloud Function with `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` ID member while 'Compute Engine' uses this default account `PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` as described in the cloud function [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam?hl=fr). But I don't have and couldn't create this 2nd gen default service account...

Thus, I gave theses IAM role to the default 1st generation service account `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` I already have:

- roles/run.invoker
- roles/firebasestorage.serviceAgent

While creating manually the cloud function, i entered this service account as trigger : `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

Also, in order to get the logs in GCP Cloud Function, I don't no why but I had to create a Google Storage Service Agent `service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with this role:

- roles/pubsub.publisher

The command to do this is the same command indicated in the terminal after the deployement failure described in the post above :

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_NAME --member=serviceAccount:service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/pubsub.editor
```

After that, deployement and function work like a charm. I hope it will help !